# Sum of odd numbers in a range

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

What is the sum of the odd numbers from 1523 through 10503, inclusive? Hint: write a while loop to accumulate the sum and print it. Then copy and paste that sum. For maximum learning, do it with a for loop as well, using range.

What I tried. I need to print the sum as a total. My answer gives me the individual runs.

```
i=1523
while i<10503:
    sum=0
    i=i+2
    sum=sum+i
    print(sum)


for i in range(1523,10503):
    print(i+2)
```

Comment: Make sure to format your code correctly when posting. Whitespace is important in Python.

Comment: I may be reading your requirement wrong, but it seems like the `sum=0` should go outside the loop.

Comment: Hint: an odd number is equal to 1 modulo 2; i.e. 3 % 2 == 1.

Comment: Quick note guys, don't use `sum` because it's a python builtin.

Comment: Maybe not "don't use `sum`", but "avoid using `sum`". It is not a law carved in stone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You assignment says "inclusive", hence you should include 10503 into the sum:

```
i = 1523
total = 0
while i <= 10503:
    total += i
    i += 2
print (total)

total = 0
for i in range (1523, 10504, 2):
    total += i
print (total)
```

Also avoid using builtin names, like `sum`. Hence I changed it to `total`.

On a side note: Although your assignment asks explicitely for control statements, you (or at least I) would implement it as:

```
print (sum (range (1523, 10504, 2) ) )
```

Comment: Amazing comprehensive answer for how concise it is. Of course there's no `reduce` over a mutating `__iadd__` method on a wrapper around a `ctypes.c_int`… :)

Answer (score 0):

As Troy said, put the `sum=0` before the loop. Then put `print(sum)` after the while loop.

Comment: I think he wasn't adding the last number since the assignment says inclusive